# jsp compile error

Tags: java, jsp, maven

I have following line in a `jsp` page from an open source project:

```
<html:option value="micg">µg</html:option>
```

When I compile it using `maven` following code is generated:

```
_jspx_th_html_005foption_005f9.setValue("micg");
    int _jspx_eval_html_005foption_005f9 = _jspx_th_html_005foption_005f9.doStartTag();
    if (_jspx_eval_html_005foption_005f9 != javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag.SKIP_BODY) {
      if (_jspx_eval_html_005foption_005f9 != javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag.EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE) {
        out = _jspx_page_context.pushBody();
        _jspx_th_html_005foption_005f9.setBodyContent((javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyContent) out);
        _jspx_th_html_005foption_005f9.doInitBody();
      }
      do {
        out.write('Â');
        out.write('µ');
        out.write('g');
        int evalDoAfterBody = _jspx_th_html_005foption_005f9.doAfterBody();
        if (evalDoAfterBody != javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTag.EVAL_BODY_AGAIN)
          break;
      } while (true);
      if (_jspx_eval_html_005foption_005f9 != javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag.EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE) {
        out = _jspx_page_context.popBody();
      }
    }
```

This is causing following error in compiling generated `java` file:

```
[javac] Compiling 1375 source files
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction 
          with -source 1.5
[javac] D:\src\WriteScript_jsp.java:2310: error: unclosed character literal
[javac]         out.write('Â');
[javac]                   ^
[javac] D:\src\WriteScript_jsp.java:2310: error: illegal character: \8218
[javac]         out.write('Â');
[javac]                     ^
[javac] D:\src\WriteScript_jsp.java:2310: error: unclosed character literal
[javac]         out.write('Â');
[javac]                      ^
[javac] D:\src\WriteScript_jsp.java:2311: error: unclosed character literal
[javac]         out.write('µ');
[javac]                   ^
[javac] D:\src\WriteScript_jsp.java:2311: error: ';' expected
[javac]         out.write('µ');
[javac]                     ^
[javac] D:\src\WriteScript_jsp.java:2311: error: unclosed character literal
[javac]         out.write('µ');
[javac]                      ^
[javac] 6 errors
```

Please help me how to  remove this error :( I am on Windows 7 64-bit and JDK version 1.7.

Comment: javac uses the default character encoding. Try using the `-encoding` option to match the character encoding of the source files.

Comment: I have no utter idea about the Maven part, but I can at least tell that the presence of the `Â` in the generated Java source indicates that you've saved the JSP source code as ISO-8859-x instead of UTF-8 (or that JSP parser is reading it as ISO-8859-x instead of UTF-8). Check/reconfigure your source code puller or editor in Maven.

Comment: Yes @BalusC It was just a shot in the dark, I checked from `Encoding` menu in Notepad++ and `Encode in UTF-8 without BOM` was checked. I checked `Convert to UTF-8` and it is compiling from that point now. There are still errors but this one is gone for good.

Comment: Have you tried to change the charset of the whole project to UTF-8?

Comment: Glad that it solved the problem. I reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The presence of the `Â` in the generated Java source indicates that you've saved the JSP source code as ISO-8859-x instead of UTF-8 (or that JSP parser is reading it as ISO-8859-x instead of UTF-8 which is unlikely). Check/reconfigure your source code editor and make sure that it saves the JSP source code as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to ensuring you have `-encoding` correct everywhere, as suggested by other responders, is to not use non-lower-ASCII characters in your file.  This can be acomplished with the `\u` escape, for example, by writing:

```
 out.write('\u006c');
```

..instead of:

```
 out.write('Â');
```

Nowhere near as pretty or convenient, but much easier to get to work in large teams, especially if you only have Scary Foreign Moon Language Characters in limited locations in your applications, as most development teams who deal with this kind of thing do.

Comment: this is coming from a generated file (jsp -> java)